# How to create custom UIViewController then subclass already created UIViewControllers with it?

Tags: ios

I have many classes subclasses of UIViewController. I would like to create another subclass of UIViewController and then make all my previous classes become subclasses of this one. Is that possible? If yes, how?

To clarify:

UIViewController > my previous UIViewControllers

now, what I would like:

UIViewController > new UIViewController > my previous UIViewControllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking up categories. They are an objective C way of extending a class. This way rather than having to go back and change your original code.

Comment: Nice tip. I'm going to check this. Call me stupid to not had set a master uiviewcontroller first.

Comment: I heard about categories before, but I've never tried. I just gave it a go, it's perfect! Thanks a lot!